# Add legends to QT Data Visualization charts

Tags: c++, qt5, data-visualization

I'm following the QT Data Visualization Surface Example to create a 3D chart, in C++, using Q3DSurface with QSurface3DSeries.  The tutorial is at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html

For the life of me, I could not figure out how to add a legend for my data series.  There is an example in QML for adding a legend, but it is does not give enough hint on where and how to do it in C++.

Does anyone know or could point me to how to add legends to the QT Data Visualization module?

Comment: Read this already? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-legend-example.html I mean, it's pure Qt C++... =)

Comment: Yep. That was for the QT Charts module. Unfortunately, the Data Visualization module does not follow the Charts framework.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Following the example there is no magic at all. The `LegendItem` is a custom class which gets some proterties from the plot itself, so why not creating an equivalent C++ class on your own? Position requires some work, but is manageable. Seems there is no Qt class for this, yet.

Comment: That might be what's needed to be done.  I was hoping that I missed something obvious so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. :(